# How to build a docker image with tensorflow-nightly and the tensorflow object detection research models

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-model-garden

Since GPU support with tensorflow-nightly is [currently broken on Google Colab](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1574) I'm trying to build my own docker image for development. However, when I install the `object_detection` package from [`tensorflow/models`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/) my nightly tensorflow package is overwritten by the version pulled in as a dependency from the `object_detection` [`setup.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py).

I'm following essentially the same steps in Google Colab but my tensorflow nightly isn't overwritten there, so I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"

RUN apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        git \
        less \
        zip

RUN curl -L -O https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.11.4/protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip && unzip protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip

RUN cp bin/protoc /usr/local/bin

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
RUN cd models/research && \
        protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && \
        cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && \
        python -m pip install .

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"
```

which I'm building with:

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter
docker build --no-cache . -f models-tf-nightly.Dockerfile -t tf-nightly-models
```

The first `print()` shows:

```
Tensorflow version: 2.5.0-dev20201129
```

but the second one shows:

```
Tensorflow version: 2.3.1
```

---

In Google Colab I'm doing essentially the same steps:

```
# Install the Object Detection API
%%bash
pip install tf-nightly-gpu
[[ -d models ]] || git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

After which

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

prints `2.5.0-dev20201201`

So somehow my Google Colab steps are preserving my nightly Tensorflow install, whereas on Docker it gets overwritten with 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `pip list` before installing the object detection package, you will see that `tf-nightly-gpu` is installed but `tensorflow` is not. When you install the object detection package, the `tensorflow` package is pulled in as a dependency. `pip` thinks it is not installed, so it installs it.

One way around this is to trick pip install thinking that the `tensorflow` package is installed. One can do this by symlinking the `tf_nightly_gpu-VERSION.dist-info` directory in `dist-packages`. I have added the lines to do this in the Dockerfile below. At the bottom of this post, I have also included a Dockerfile which implements some best practices to minimize image size.

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"

RUN apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        git \
        less \
        zip

# Trick pip into thinking that the 'tensorflow' package is installed.
# Installing `object_detection` attempts to install the 'tensorflow' package.
# Name the symlink with the suffix from tf_nightly_gpu.
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
RUN ln -s tf_nightly_gpu-* tensorflow-$(ls -d1 tf_nightly_gpu* | sed 's/tf_nightly_gpu-\(.*\)/\1/')

WORKDIR /tf
RUN curl -L -O https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.11.4/protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip && unzip protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip

RUN cp bin/protoc /usr/local/bin

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
RUN cd models/research && \
        protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && \
        cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && \
        python -m pip install .

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"
```

---

Here is a Dockerfile that leads to a slightly smaller image (0.22 GB uncompressed). Notable changes are clearing the `apt` lists and using `--no-cache-dir` in `pip install`.

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        less \
        zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Trick pip into thinking that the 'tensorflow' package is installed.
# Installing `object_detection` attempts to install the 'tensorflow' package.
# Name the symlink with the suffix from tf_nightly_gpu.
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
RUN ln -s tf_nightly_gpu-* tensorflow-$(ls -d1 tf_nightly_gpu* | sed 's/tf_nightly_gpu-\(.*\)/\1/')

WORKDIR /tf
RUN curl -L -O https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.11.4/protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    unzip protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip && \
    cp bin/protoc /usr/local/bin && \
    rm -r protoc-3.11.4-linux-x86_64.zip bin/

# Upgrade pip.
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
WORKDIR models/research
RUN protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && \
    cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && \
    python -m pip install  --no-cache-dir .

RUN python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(f'Tensorflow version: {tf.__version__}')"
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! I changed the `ln` to `RUN ln -s tf_nightly_gpu-* tensorflow-$(ls -d1 tf_nightly_gpu* | sed 's/tf_nightly_gpu-\(.*\)/\1/')` so that I don't have to edit my Dockerfile when `tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-jupyter` gets a version bump. Also, thanks for the image size tips, great stuff.

Comment: Thanks @mgalgs - I updated the answer with your improvements.